# ts(2339) Property 'ariaLabel' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Tags: typescript

I have an array of HTMLElements that all have an aria label and I'm trying to get those labels with the following code:

```
const opponentsPkm = Array.from(
    activeRoom.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>(".rightbar .picon")
  );
  const names = opponentsPkm.map((x) => x.ariaLabel);
```

however I get the typescript error "Property 'ariaLabel' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'."
Since the aria label isnt a required property I havent been able to figure out how to solve the typescript error.
The html elements in the array are all span elements that look like this:

```
<span class="picon has-tooltip" data-tooltip="pokemon|1|3" aria-label="Landorus (Landorus-Therian) (84%)"></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the `aria-label` via the `getAttribute` function.

```js
const opponentsPkm = Array.from(activeRoom.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>(".rightbar .picon"));
const names = opponentsPkm.map((x) => x.getAttribute('aria-label'));
```